# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'product' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

Whenever I click on Edit Button, I am getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'product' available as request attribute
```

, not able to understand what's wrong here

My Product controller is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/product/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String EditProducts(@PathVariable("id") String ProductID,Model model){
    System.out.println("ProductID");
    product = productDAO.get(ProductID);
    model.addAttribute("product", product);
    model.addAttribute("ProductList",productDAO.list());
    return "product";
}
```

My product.jsp page is as follows

```
<c:url var="product" value="/product/add" />
<form:form method="POST" commandName="product" action="${product}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr>
   <td><form:label path="id"><spring:message text="ID" /></form:label></td>
   <c:choose>
   <c:when test="${!empty listValue.getId()}">
   <td><form:input path="id" disabled="true" readonly="true"/></td>
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
   <td><form:input class="form-control" path="id" pattern=".{4,7}" required="true" title="id should contain 4 to 7 characters" /></td>
   </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input class="form-control" path="name" type="text" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="price">Price</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input class="form-control" path="price" type="text" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><form:label path="category_id">Category ID</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input class="form-control" path="category_id" type="text" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><form:label path="supplier_id">Supplier ID</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input class="form-control" path="supplier_id" type="text" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td><form:label path="imge">Image</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="imge" type="file" name="imge" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>     
<td colspan="2">
<c:if test="${!empty productList.name}">
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Edit Product"/>"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${empty productList.name}">
<input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Add Product"/>" />
</c:if></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</div>
</form:form>
<center><h1>${msg}</h1></center>
<c:if test="${not empty ProductList}">
<center><h1>List</h1></center>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>product Id</th>
        <th>product Name</th>
        <th>product Price</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Supplier Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${ProductList}" varStatus="status">
    <tbody>
               <tr>
                <td style="width:10% ;height:2%"><img style="width:2% ;height:2%" src='<c:url value="/resources\img/${listValue.getId()}.jpg"/>'/></td>                 
                <td>${listValue.getId()}</td>
                <td>${listValue.getName()}</td>
                <td>${listValue.getPrice()}</td>
                <td> 
                <c:out  value="${CategoryList[status.index]}"/> 
                </td>
                <td><c:out  value="${SupplierList[status.index]}"/></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='product/edit/${listValue.getId()}' />" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a> / <a href="<c:url value='product/remove/${listValue.getId()}' /> " class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
               </tr>
              </c:forEach>      
  </tbody>
  </table>
    </c:if>
```

I have to get the data populated into the form when I click the edit button. I am a newbie and having a trouble in this section, I have viewed similar question, but not able to understand, please help. If needed more details, I'll provide them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the product object so that your jsp can load its data. It also helps you when you want to reload the page without loosing data after validating the form, for instance.

```
@RequestMapping("/newproduct")
public ModelAndView form(@Valid Product product){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("product");
    return mv;
}
```